Stop iframe of jumping to the middle of it while loading
Wanted to add a twinmotion embed onto the website, but everytime I scroll the website the problems still persists.
Link to the website (try to scroll you will see the jump): portal-estate.pl/gdynia/
This is my code snippet:
<div >
<iframe  scrolling="no" pointer-events:none; id="twinmotion-iframe"
title="Embedded panorama 'WERSJA 2, PARTER SPACER'" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless"
allow="fullscreen; gyroscope; accelerometer; magnetometer; execution-while-out-of-viewport;
execution-while-not-rendered; xr-spatial-tracking;"
allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"
src="https://twinmotion.unrealengine.com/panorama/swxKD0FE3K7GI5BQ?lang=pl-PL" 
loading="lazy" 
data-cookiescript="accepted"
data-cookieconsent="Necessary"
>
    
</iframe>
</div>



<style>
    
    
    #twinmotion-iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px;
    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        #twinmotion-iframe {
            height: 600px;
            
        }
    }

    @media (max-width: 480px) {
        #twinmotion-iframe {
          width: 100%;
          min-height: 300px;

        }
    }
</style>



I expect it to load in a background without disrupting the scrolling flow...
or otherwise make the iframe to stop doing weird jumps when loading.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
